# tensorflow pip and conda clash

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pip, conda

I am attempting to install tensorflow 1.8 to 1.10.1.  Unfortunately, I installed it with both pip and conda, and while it worked when I tried to upgrade to tensorflow 1.10.1 I get the below error message.  I have attempted to remove it with both pip and conda as well as create a new conda environment and install it fresh in conda.  With no other versions of tensorflow installed (for any other conda env as well) I ran:

```
conda create -n testing python=3.6.5 scipy numpy jupyter scikit-learn matplotlib seaborn nltk tensorflow
```

Then when I import tensorflow I get the same error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/anaconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     57 
---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     59   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import __version__

/anaconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in <module>()
     27             return _mod
---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
     29     del swig_import_helper

/anaconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     23             try:
---> 24                 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
     25             finally:

/anaconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.6/imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
    242         else:
--> 243             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    244     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:

/anaconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.6/imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
    342             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 343         return _load(spec)
    344 

ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): Symbol not found: __ZN10tensorflow10DeviceBase16eigen_cpu_deviceEv
  Referenced from: /anaconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
  Expected in: /Users/avanders/tensorflow_libs/lib/libtensorflow_framework.so
 in /anaconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-64156d691fe5> in <module>()
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

/anaconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py in <module>()
     20 
     21 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
---> 22 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
     23 
     24 try:

/anaconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py in <module>()
     47 import numpy as np
     48 
---> 49 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     50 
     51 # Protocol buffers

/anaconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     72 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     73 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 74   raise ImportError(msg)
     75 
     76 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/anaconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/anaconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): Symbol not found: __ZN10tensorflow10DeviceBase16eigen_cpu_deviceEv
  Referenced from: /anaconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
  Expected in: /Users/avanders/tensorflow_libs/lib/libtensorflow_framework.so
 in /anaconda3/envs/testing/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: what version of glibc are you running? TensorFlow requires glibc > 2.17. You could try to find yours by running ldd --version

Comment: @CAta.RAy - I am using OSX High Sierra which I believe doesn't have glibc or ldd.  I did try to run otool -L with the file that was missing an object and glibc was not listed as one of the dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the problem was a conflict in versions with the go wrappers I had installed for the tensorflow library.  Once I updated those wrappers to the same version a conda install worked.